# How to display Woocommerce catagories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display woocommerce products catagories in my wordpress sidebar theme. 
what is the code for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for to get the product category.

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($term->ID) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';    
}
```

Comment: please paste the full code for display woocommerce all product catagories. it would be good be me.

Comment: i want to display catagories in <li></li>, if i do will the shortcode, the css will be out of my sidebar.

Comment: I have updated code which will show all category in li

Comment: Please send me the code

Comment: I have updated ans please use the ans code

Comment: oh thank u man. i link the link to on catagories. Can u please update the code again for catagories name.

Comment: Good Thanks for using stackexchange have nice day.

Comment: Brother, can u please insert the link on catagories to move this on catagory page ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29754/discussion-between-nadzhq-and-mitul).